# Error message when uploading an image

Tags: 6, media, ajax

During Image upload, I get an 'Http error 0 occurred' when the file size is larger than the allowed maximum file size. Is this a correct behavior? and how would I provide a better error message. I have tried this in different browsers all show this message and changed settings in php ini file based on discussions on this topic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this occur in other browsers too?

Comment: yea tried in IE, FF and chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to see this error when you try to upload an image file that PHP has an issue with, either because it is larger than the allowed maximum file size in PHP or because trying to process the image (ex. for creating thumbnails) is consuming more memory than you have allowed in your php.ini.

There is a [*monster* thread](http://drupal.org/node/434394) on this topic over at Drupal.org but the key takeaways are to try and increase these two values (php file upload or memory limit) or to switch your imageapi library from PHP GD over to ImageMagick to avoid the memory constraints.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll try switching to Imagemagick.